# Disconnect backend Writer from BufferedWriter

Tags: java, java-io

A `java.io.BufferedWriter#close()` also closes the `Writer` that was given to the constructor.

But I have (provided by third party; can't be changed) a special subclass that I only need to write *part* of the output with. More data need to be written to the underlying `OutputStream` further up the call stack. So while I can just `#flush` the writer instead of `#close`ing it, I can't guarantee it won't be closed by the garbage collector before the caller is finished with the `OutputStream`.

Can I stop the propagation of `#close` to the `OutputStream`? Preferably without writing all the potentially very large data into a temporary array.

Comment: A `BufferedWriter` getting GC-ed doesn't close the underlying writer (the same is true for a `OutputStreamWriter`). Neither one has a `finalize` method or any other mechanism to do that. Simply not calling `close` should be sufficient.

Comment: Why don't you just make a custom `Writer` that propagates the closing?

Comment: @dan1st, you mean stops the closing, right? That's always an option. I would just expect something to already exist.